# Erlang supervisor silently failing to start

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

I am an Erlang beginner, learning OTP.
I received a `noproc` error when trying to talk to a supervisor in runtime. In fact, that supervisor's `start_link` (implemented by me, not supervisor:start_link()) seemed not to be executed, as the `io:fwrite` in its first line wasn't even put out.

It turned out the issue was that one of the supervisor's children was missing some `gen_server` callback functions (which were not used by the application). The compiler logged a warning about that and that's it, no errors when I started the application. I'm not sure what is going on, but shouldn't there be some error indication happening?

In case it's important, that's how the child spec of the supervisor itself looks like:

```
ElementSup = {sc_element_sup,
                    {sc_element_sup, start_link, []},
                    permanent, 2000, supervisor, [sc_element]},
```

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: With `$ erlc -o ebin src/*erl` , the source is the application at : https://github.com/erlware/Erlang-and-OTP-in-Action-Source/blob/master/chapter_07/simple_cache/src/sc_event_logger.erl , I left out the last four callback functions.

Answer (score 2):

First, I get a compiler error:

```
2> c(my_worker).
my_worker.erl:5: function terminate/2 undefined
error
```

Then, the supervisor lets me know that it didn't start because it couldn't start all its children:

```
3> my_sup:start_link().                  
** exception exit: {shutdown,
                    {failed_to_start_child,my_worker, 
                     {'EXIT',
                      {undef,
                       [{my_worker,start_link,[],[]},
                        {supervisor,do_start_child,2,
                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,365}]},
                        {supervisor,start_children,3,
                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,348}]},
                        {supervisor,init_children,2, 
                         [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,314}]},
                        {gen_server,init_it,2,
                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,365}]},
                        {gen_server,init_it,6,
                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,333}]},
                        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                         [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}}}}
```

> In fact, that supervisor's start_link seemed not to be executed, as
> the io:fwrite in its first line wasn't even put out.

The supervisor's `start_link()` function is defined in the OTP library, so you can't have an `io:fwrite()` in that function.  You can add an `io:fwrite()` line to a function that you define, which in turn calls `supervisor:start_link()`, for instance:

```
start_my_supervisor() ->
    io:format("hello~n"),
    Args = [],
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Args).
```

The "hello" message displays just fine in my erlang shell output.

Comment: My bad, I didn't mean `supervisor:start_link` but `start_link()` in my supervisor, which seemed not to be executed when the callback functions were missing in the child module. the io:fwrite() only logged once I corrected the mistake, therefore the impression that it wasn't even run and the supervisor wasn't started even, because there was also no error at all.